# Grep specific words between quotation marks

Tags: bash, grep, tags

Lets say I have a line like this:

```
<group description="" name="voice_guidance" comment="Missing description!" status="0">
```

I wish to grep with a bash script only the comment saying:

> Missing description!

Comment: Could you clarify your question? At least, add an example

Comment: Edited. Pressed enter a bit too soon. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want the comment, you can use this:
`grep -Po 'comment="\K[^"]*'`

`\K` means to only output the part following from there and then all the non-quote characters following are output.

Comment: Excelent! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Bert Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Completely forgot to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use straightforward solution:

```
grep '"Missing description!"' filename.html
```

Where `filename.html` is a target file.

Here is an example output:

[image: grep file]

P.S. In such when I see HTML and RegEx both present in the same question, I recommend to read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5091346

Comment: Good idea, but the text is not always the same.

Comment: Sorry, @Bert. Seems that your question is not clear enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use the perl-regexp (`-P`) in @rubystallion's fine answer, use:

```
$ grep -o "comment=\"[^\"]\+" file | grep -o "[^\"]\+$"
Missing description!
```